# Xamarin Android : LinearLayout background and Drawable Left do not display correctly

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin

So I had an application that worked weel on API 24. And then I updated my phone to API 26, now the linearLayout Background and the textview drawable left do not show anymore. I have no Idea why and it seems like it's not a common problem, I did not find any topics talking about this problem.

So Here how it looks on API 24 :

[image]

And here how it looks on API 26 :
[image]

I don't know where to look since I did not change anything in my code..

I hope someone could just tell me where to look.. Thanks in advance

PS: My App is supposed to target API  27

Comment: Did you run your code in custom Android firmware? Please run your code in native android firmware. If this issue is still existed.

Comment: I guess no one will see this haha, but the bug was because I did have some images in the folder anydpi-v26 and it seems like it causes the wrong display, I just deleted the folder and it works fine now.

Comment: Oops, thanks for your sharing.